# Rank function in MySQL c# windows form application

Tags: c#, sql, rank

I'm building this app using SQL and I'm finding a problem on how to get rank column in my datagridview, I used this code but it's not working, it's just classifying students without displaying rank column.

```cs
SetConnection();
sqlconn.Open();
sqlCmd = sqlconn.CreateCommand()
**string CommandText = "select * from Student ORDER BY average DESC";**
DB = new SQLiteDataAdapter(CommandText, sqlconn);
DS.Reset();
DB.Fill(DS);
sqlDT = DS.Tables[0];
dataGridView1.DataSource = sqlDT;
sqlconn.Close();
```

Comment: Sample data and the desired output would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `rank()` function:

```
select s.*, rank() over (order by average desc) as ranking
from Student s
order by average desc;
```